# file exists with condition today's date

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder where files are dumped with timestamps...
filename_ver20130405121320.csv

I wish to create a batch script that makes sure 5 files have been created with todays date.

im guessing i will need to use a for loop with a date limit of today.

```
FOR /r %foldername% %%g IN (*.csv) DO (
    echo %%~nxg 
)
```

using a forfiles statement lists the files, is it possible to use a counter and +=1 every time it displays a filename?

```
forfiles /S /P %foldername% /m *.csv /d 0
```

the logic is

```
if number of files in a foldername is less than 5 where file created is today

echo error! missing files
```

any help would be much appreciated

date returned on machine as Mon 22/07/2013
use this to set date

```
:: set date 
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET setDate=%dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%
```

Comment: Easier to do if you specify the format returned as %date% on your machine - notine whether the various components are leading-zero-filled or not.

Comment: edited question to include response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this and it seems to work so far

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%I in ("%date%") do set today=%%I
for /f "tokens=5" %%G in ('dir %foldername% /a-d ^| find "%today%"') do (
set /a fileCounter += 1 
echo %%G
)

echo %fileCounter%
```

Comment: Try creating a file `filename_ver2013040512132.csv` - this contains your datestring, but doesn't fit your mask. Actually, this code would detect ANY filename containing the datestring.

Comment: yes, i changed the spec and decided i wanted all files with today's date.
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET yyyy=2013
SET mm=07
SET dd=22
SET count=0
FOR /f %%g IN ('dir /b /a-d *%yyyy%%mm%%dd%????.csv') DO (
 SET filename=%%~ng
 SET filename=!filename:~-12,-4!
 if "!filename!"=="%yyyy%%mm%%dd%" SET /a count+=1
)
ECHO %count%
GOTO :EOF
```

I've simply set `yyyy`,`mm`,`dd` to constants, obviously - just poke your date-decoder in as appropriate.

Note that you could prefix the filemask with a directoryname if required - and enclose the entire filemask in "rabbit's ears" if there are spaces or other confounding characters in the resultant mask.

Important: the filemask is merely a primary filter. The `dir` would list a file named `filename_ver2013040512132.csv` for instance (1 digit missing...) so the gymnastics with the processing would still be required.

I'm also assuming relatively sane filenames. Likely `!` in a filename would cause conniptions.

Answer (score 0):

This may work (untested): edited to check only the date in yyyymmdd format

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
for /f %%a in ('dir "*ver%datestamp%*.csv" /b /a-d^|find /c /v "" ') do (
if %%a LSS 5 echo files are missing
)
```